# Unexpected File Pointer Traversal Behaviour in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, text-files

This is my code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ex.c","w+");
    fputs("Hello World\nFile Pointer",fp);
    printf("Text - \n");
    rewind(fp);
    char ch;
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        printf("File pointer  - %d and letter - ",ftell(fp));
        if(ch=='\t')
            printf("tab");
        else
        if(ch=='\n')
            printf("newline");
        else
            putchar(ch);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And this is the output I got -

```
Text -
File pointer  - 1 and letter - H
File pointer  - 2 and letter - e
File pointer  - 3 and letter - l
File pointer  - 4 and letter - l
File pointer  - 5 and letter - o
File pointer  - 6 and letter -
File pointer  - 7 and letter - W
File pointer  - 8 and letter - o
File pointer  - 9 and letter - r
File pointer  - 10 and letter - l
File pointer  - 11 and letter - d
File pointer  - 13 and letter - newline
File pointer  - 14 and letter - F
File pointer  - 15 and letter - i
File pointer  - 16 and letter - l
File pointer  - 17 and letter - e
File pointer  - 18 and letter -
File pointer  - 19 and letter - P
File pointer  - 20 and letter - o
File pointer  - 21 and letter - i
File pointer  - 22 and letter - n
File pointer  - 23 and letter - t
File pointer  - 24 and letter - e
File pointer  - 25 and letter - r
```

But what I was expecting was -

```
Text -
File pointer  - 1 and letter - H
File pointer  - 2 and letter - e
File pointer  - 3 and letter - l
File pointer  - 4 and letter - l
File pointer  - 5 and letter - o
File pointer  - 6 and letter -
File pointer  - 7 and letter - W
File pointer  - 8 and letter - o
File pointer  - 9 and letter - r
File pointer  - 10 and letter - l
File pointer  - 11 and letter - d
File pointer  - 12 and letter - newline
File pointer  - 13 and letter - F
File pointer  - 14 and letter - i
File pointer  - 15 and letter - l
File pointer  - 16 and letter - e
File pointer  - 17 and letter -
File pointer  - 18 and letter - P
File pointer  - 19 and letter - o
File pointer  - 20 and letter - i
File pointer  - 21 and letter - n
File pointer  - 22 and letter - t
File pointer  - 23 and letter - e
File pointer  - 24 and letter - r
```

The one particular line where it says -

```
 File pointer  - 13 and letter - newline
```

I wasn't expecting the jump of file pointer value from 11 to 13, but was expecting it to change from 11 to 12.

What is the reason behind this behaviour?

But when I change this line in the code - `fputs("Hello World\nFile Pointer",fp);`

to - `fputs("Hello World\tFile Pointer",fp);`

I get the output I expected.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Try again opening the file in binary mode or open in a hex-editor. If that still is a problem, see [ask].

Comment: add `else if(ch=='\r') printf("carriage return");` to the checks.

Comment: So a newline is two bytes wide in a Windows text file, carriage return and line feed.

Comment: @EOF If the file is opened in text mode, you'll never read the `\r` character.

Comment: @Barmar What if you're reading a windows-created text file on a POSIX system?

Comment: @EOF This program creates the file that it's reading, so they can't be on different systems. But in the general case, it depends on whether you transferred the file in text or binary mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be running this on Windows, which uses DOS format for text files. In this format, a newline is represented in the file as two bytes: `Carriage Return` followed by `Line Feed`. So it has to read 2 byte from the file to read the single "newline" character, and this is reflected in the offset returned by `ftell()`.

If you ran the program on Unix you would get the result you were expecting, since it uses just `Line Feed` as the newline character.